# Secure erase drive in Single User Mode

Tags: security, disk-utility, disk-format

My 2007 Macbook Pro has suffered from a failure of its GPU and will now only boot in Single User mode.

I want to sell it on eBay for spares, but obviously I don't want a hard drive with live data on it ending up on eBay.

I know you can destroy a drive's contents with a secure erase in Disk Utility, but as I said, I can't boot into any mode that requires graphics because the GPU is dead.

How do I secure erase the machine's drive in Single User mode?

Comment: If you're selling for spares, you could sell sans-HDD (which won't effect it's value much, as it's a four year old used HDD) and not need to worry about it?

Comment: That thought had occurred, but it's one of those pre-unibody machines that are not exactly easy to get into.  I'd prefer avoiding that if I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally from the command line, you would use the **diskutil** command with the **zeroDisk, randomDisk** or **secureErase** options to securely wipe a disk. However, I would imagine this doesn't work on the disk you've just booted from. So I suspect you'll either have to find another Mac and connect yours in target disk mode via a Firewire cable, or physically remove the drive and connect it to another Mac using a disk caddy, to wipe it the way you wish.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to boot an external drive (including the installation DVD) in single user mode:

**Hold Option as you turn the power on, select** the DVD/HDD **with the arrow keys then press and hold Command+S+Return**, holding them down until you see the now-familiar-for-you console boot: at which point it would be possible to use a whole disk shredder as mentioned by scottishwildcat.

Comment: Thanks, I've searched a way to boot from different partition in single user / safe mode. Actually, there is no need to hold **Return** key, just press it once.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same task. And finally I've found the way to do it without other mac.

1. Boot in single user mode from external hdd / recovery. (see @Ryccardo [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/89927/22498)). Note: you can't erase partition you booted from.
2. Create new partition in place of one you want to erase:

   `newfs_hfs -J 0 /dev/diskXsY`

   Make sure to change X & Y in disk**X**s**Y** to proper values.
   *Note: create with journal (-J option) to override previous journal, which can make impossible to mount partition in single user mode.*
3. Mount created partition.
4. Fill partition with (random) data. The easiest way is to create large file(s) to occupy all space. You can use `openssl rand` or `dd of=… bs=… count=…` as described in answers of this [question](https://superuser.com/q/470949/85833).
5. Optional: securely remove created file(s) with [`srm`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/srm.1.html).

*Note: **maybe** this method will not fully erase data such as previous files' names / dir structures, if such data stored in some system areas of fs. I'm not sure, because I don't know how HFS+ stored. But in my case it's not a problem.*

Answer (score -2):

If you want to completely wipe it, I'd think you could type this in single-user mode, hitting return after each "-----": /sbin/mount -uw / ----- rm -rf *

Comment: Once you have unmounted `/`, where exactly would the binary for `rm` come from?

Comment: @patrix: his reasoning is actually sound (`mount -uw` means remount while making writable and the command is obviously loaded in RAM before it starts acting), but apart from not being a secure erasing tool (at least with the supplied command line) -- what if it fails? How would you repeat it?